# How does Stack Overflow Unanswered Questions Listing in Specific Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions

When I am trying to View my Question, I know it is unanswered so I went to Unanswered Question list in a tag but am unable to see my question in the lists that are shown.

I can go my question by my profile.

How do I get my question to appear at the top of list? Is there any-way and how to know my question's page in the list?

As a User I need to go my question unanswered question how can I go to that?

Comment: which question? this one? I can see one by you from 10 days ago, etc..

Comment: if possible can u just send me the link. i need it for my issue

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822639/kendo-ui-datepicker-tab-key-toggling-not-working-in-firefox-when-changing-the-ac) is what @MarcGravell tried to link.  But if I am understanding the question correctly, the "Unanswered" questions tab is listed by net score and then by time.  Since your question has a 0 net score and was asked on July 18th, it is way back on [page 727](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery?page=727&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15)

Comment: @SundarRajan the only link I can send you that won't be out of date almost immediately is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822639/kendo-ui-datepicker-tab-key-toggling-not-working-in-firefox-when-changing-the-ac ; that is visible off your profile page (just click on your own name at the top of the page on stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah i know it how can i get in tag wise not by gng into my profile. Am asking how does its working in SO? I can go and get my question in my profile but how it is working in tag wise?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah i got it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 What if the net score are same to the other question dnt say then by time its not working  i checked it out.

Comment: @SundarRajan there are dozens of different ways to sort and view questions.  Don't just say "tag-wise" because that could be multiple ways.  You specifically mentioned the "Unanswered" question list by tag.  Your question is there.  That list is sorted by score then time.  Your post is now on [page 728](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery?page=728&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15) when looking at all unanswered questions tagged [tag:jquery].  And will keep moving down as newer questions come in and other questions get voted up.

Comment: @SundarRajan Noted :)

Comment: @SundarRajan but if that still doesn't answer your question, then I suggest you edit this question to explain how you are trying to find your question (specifically how have you tried to find it) and I'm sure someone can tell you where your question is.  But if your entire point is trying to find it to get attention and get an answer, then I suggest you read [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: @SundarRajan so your question isn't about finding your question, it is about how to get attention to your question?

Comment: @psubsee2003 in my requirement i asked to two things  1) I need a answer like how to get my question in front list is there any-way and 2) how to know my question's page in the list?

Comment: @psubsee2003 oops one more too :)

Comment: @SundarRajan why do you need to find it on the unanswered question list?  That question makes no sense.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - he wants his question to appear in the list so other people will see it and (hopefully) answer it. I think.

Comment: @ChrisF ultimately, I think he is just trying to figure out how to bump his question.  But he is stuck on the idea of finding his question in the list and I'm trying to figure that one out because I fail to see the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dozens of ways to sort and filter questions depending on what page you are on, but from the [`/questions` page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), there are 6 methods

> [image]

- **Newest** simply orders the questions by age
- **Featured** shows all questions with bounties attached to them and they are sorted by the age of the bounty, with the closest expiring bounties listed first
- **Frequent** simply lists questions that are linked as duplicates (i.e. commonly asked questions)
- **Votes** lists all questions in decending order of score, and then by time from newest to oldest
- **Active** lists questions by most recent activity.  "Activity" in this context includes editing, posting of an answer, deleting an answer.  It does **not** include comments.
- **Unanswered** lists questions without accepted or upvoted answers in decending order of score and then by date from newest to oldest.

These 6 tabs also appear when filtering questions by tag, so you can get the same options when you filter the question list by tag or by tags.

Ultimately there is no way to bump a question to the top of most of these as they depending on criteria outside of your control, such as votes and age.  You do have some influence on the "Active" tab as you can edit your question, which will push it to the top here.  But when you edit your question, you need to make sure your edit is substantial.  Tiny edits, just for the purposes of bumping your question are frowned upon by the community, which will only bring negative attention to your question, and if you do it enough, a moderator may ask you to stop.

As for finding your question within each of the lists.  It is a relatively trivial process, once you know how the lists are sorted.  But there is no way to do it automatically, you just need to go looking for it.

---

Ultimately, it looks like your entire question is about getting an answer to your old question.  I would encourage you to read [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) on Meta.StackExchange.  It describes the best ways to get attention to your question.

To quote the accept answer:

> 1. You can "bump" your thread by editing the question to provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Some times I eventually bring about enough understanding to realise the answer, and thus post a resolution to my own problem.
> 2. If you have at least 75 rep points, you can offer a bounty, promising to give some of your points to the person who correctly answers your question.
>
> Do not post your question a second time, as it will be closed as a duplicate of your first question.